# Splitting inconsistent data

Tags: excel, text, split

I've looked everywere but haven't found anything for this specific problem.

I know how to split data in excel, but I only see tutorials and questions where they are working with data that you know where to split it.

For example : USA - England, you know where to split, the first '-'. But how to split : South-Korea - England.

And let's even say you want to split it at the spaces, you can still have a case of, for example : Northern Ireland - England.

I've tried my best to state the question as clear as possible.

Comment: I can also accept some kind of visual basic method that splits the data at a certain point with some checks

Comment: are there cases where the second part is more than one word?

Comment: The fact that it is inconsistent makes it impossible for Excel to know which is a true split and which are not.  Excel needs set rules and connot intuit.  Unless you can create a list of all possible countries to which excel can compare this will be nearly impossible.

Comment: There is a true split, ' - '  (space + '-' + space), but that isn't an option because I can only put 1 char for splitting

Comment: Do a Find and Replace (ctrl+h to bring up the dialog box) on your data and replace ' - ' with a unique character not found in your data, such as | (the pipe character), and then split the data using that unique character.  Alternately you could use a formula to extract what you want to two different cells.